# Regular Expression to validate empty anchor with href and not empty anchor with name

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Earlier I was using following RegExp for validating anchor with HREF attribute should have text in it:

```
//regex for invalid anchor tag like: <a href="#"/> or <a href="#"> </a> 
var pattern = new RegExp('<a [^>]*(/>|>\\s*</a>)', 'g');
```

Now I have additional validation requirement that it should show valid if anchor with name attribute has no text as shown in folowing example:

```
<a href="www.google.com">the link</a> Don't Match
<a name="google"></a> Don't Match
<a href="www.google.com">&nbsp;</a> Match
<a href="www.google.com"></a> Match
<a name="google">the link</a> Match
```

I am using following code to match with the Regular Expression:

```
function validateText(text, rteObj) {
    //regex for invalid anchor tag like: <a href="#"/> or <a href="#"> </a> 
    var pattern = new RegExp('<a [^>]*(/>|>\\s*</a>)', 'g');
    var textMatch = text.match(pattern);

    if (textMatch) {
        rteObj.findParentByType("tabpanel").activate(rteObj.findParentByType("panel"));
        rteObj.markInvalid("Please remove the invalid anchor tags from the text content");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thank you,
Greetings.

Comment: I just need a Regular Expression in var pattern which validate the above four scenario in example. Does that answer your question?

Comment: No. What have **you** already tried to achieve what you want and what did it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is what you wanted:

```
<a.*(?=name=\"([^\"]*)\")[^>]*>([^$|\s+]*)<\/a>
```

[Working example 1](http://regex101.com/r/gF0nF8/2)

It will catch `<a name="google"></a>` (as being valid in your case) but not `<a name="google">the link</a>`.

#### EDIT 1:

Based on your comments, the following *regex* will perform reversed logic:

```
<a.*(?=name=\"([^\"]*)\")[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>
```

[Working example 2](http://regex101.com/r/kO9wX9/1)

#### EDIT 2:

Based on your additional request to match `<a href="#"> </a>`:

```
<a.*(?=href=\"([^\"]*)\")[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>
```

[Working example 3](http://regex101.com/r/kO9wX9/2)

#### EDIT 3:

Based on questioner comments, to validate only empty values, for example `<a href="#"> </a>` but not `<a href="#">The link</a>`:

```
<a.*(?=href=\"([^\"]*)\")[^>]*>([^\s+]+|[^\S+]+)<\/a>
```

[Working Example 4](http://regex101.com/r/kO9wX9/3)

#### EDIT 4:

As questioner always editing the question, here is the final (last) update:

```
<a.*(?=href=\"([^\"]*)\")[^>]*>([^\s+]+|[^\S+]+|\w*)<\/a>|<a.*(?=name=\"([^\"]*)\")[^>]*>(\s*\S+.*)<\/a>
```

It will validate:

```
<a href="www.google.com">the link</a> Don't Match
<a name="google"></a> Don't Match
<a href="www.google.com">&nbsp;</a> Match
<a href="google.com"></a> Match
<a name="google">The link</a> Match
```

[Working example 5](http://regex101.com/r/kO9wX9/5)

Comment: @user2967957 It's not what you have written in your question. I will update my answer

Comment: I have the updated the question now, I hope it make sense now.

Comment: @user2967957 I would recommend to look at Bootstrap, for instance, and not to re-invent a bicycle. It has all that you need (most likely). http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: Hi Rostovtsev, can it also cover one more scenario in which it can match <a href="#">&nbsp;</a>.I know I didn't covered this one in my question, it will be great if that expression cover this also.

Comment: `&nbsp;` is HTML entry. Do you that or just a regular whitespace?

Comment: No need to match &nbsp; not white space because I am using it to validate the value got from editor.

Comment: Take a look at my last edit, and please accept my answer in case it was helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks Rostovtsev, for all your answer and patience.

Comment: Hey Rostovtsev, In working example 3 we are missing the one scenario that is:<a href="#">The link </a> Invalid. Please update the working example 3 with this.

Comment: @Rohit Not sure what you wanted? *Regex* would catch `<a href="#">The link </a>`. Is that what you wanted? That example shows what it catches and what it's not.

Comment: No it should not catch <a href="#">The link </a>. In test string of working example 3 we have four scenario please add one more which is <a href="#">The link </a> Invalid.

Comment: If I understood correctly of what you wanted, then see updated answer.

Comment: Its not working its matching the new scenario, means its making it valid.

Comment: It doesn't match `<a href="#">The link </a> Invalid` - just what you said and wanted in the comments above. You said: *Please add one more which is <a href="#">The link </a> Invalid.*

Comment: I will request read my question I have updated my question how it should work then you get idea what is my requirement. <a href="#">The link </a> Invalid is doing opposite in my function what I want.

Comment: @Rohit You must write your question more clearly, so it's easily understood. The last edit of your was clear, previous ones were not.